# How to write a query to hide one column in result

Tags: mysql

I have a table in that table I have

```
column1, column2, column3, column4, column5, column6,
column7, column8, column9, column10
```

I have to write a query to show all columns except `column2` and `column3`.

Comment: Just select the specific columns you want to show.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT column1, column4, column5, column6, column7, column8, column9, column10 
FROM YOUR_TABLE;
```

Comment: thank you
what if i have 100 columns like column1,column2,column3........................column100

Comment: are u using clear sql or some backend for work with db? if u have it - u can prepare select  in your backend project